# How to update table using query parameter in Html Agility Pack using C#

Tags: html, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I've been parsing this Url with Html Agility Pack:

http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/light-sweet-crude_quotes_settlements_options.html"

The default table displayed is always the closest contract date and the current date.

I have no problem parsing the complete page above but if I ask for another date I can't seem to get a new table when I add a query parameter to get another date:

eg. http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/light-sweet-crude_quotes_settlements_options.html?tradeDate=03/07/2018"

This still returns the table for the current date. ie. 03/08/2018

However it does work if I add another query for contract month as well:

eg. http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/light-sweet-crude_quotes_settlements_options.html?optionExpiration=190-M18&tradeDate=03/07/2018"

But if I then query:

eg. http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/light-sweet-crude_quotes_settlements_options.html?optionExpiration=190-M18&tradeDate=03/06/2018"

....it will not give me the table for 03/06/2018.

It only appears to update the html for me **when I change two or more** query parameters in the Url. I'm fairly much a Noob with Html so I'm not sure if it's something to do with the actual website 'blocking' my request. Or does it expect some 'user interaction'?

The very 'basic' core of my code is:

```
    using HtmlAgilityPack;

    HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument { OptionFixNestedTags = true };         
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();           
    htmlDoc = web.Load(url);
```

A step in the right direction would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a ajax site. the WepPage contains JS that makes Ajax queries by filtering done.
Therefore you do not need the `html-agility-pack` but the [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

the URL is:
http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/Settlements/Options/Settlements//190/OOF?monthYear=LOM18&strategy=DEFAULT&tradeDate=03/08/2018&pageSize=50&_=1520581128693

you need build the url query string, download th text with WebClient.DownloadString and convert it to POCO with JSON.NET.

Comment: Thank you very much dovid. I have upvoted your answer. It is recorded as such but it will not show until I have 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I've posted this answer for anyone else reading this post. Please feel free to comment or edit the post. Thanks again to Dovid for the suggestions. I cannot vouch for absolute syntax validity, however it's pretty close. The code loads a webpage table in Json format then saves to a file. There is a method for loading from the Json file as well. The code is 'as-is' and is not meant to be a copy and paste job, just a reference to how I did it.

```
using Newtonsoft;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

private string _jsonStr;
private string _tableUrlStr = "http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/Settlements/Options/Settlements//190/OOF?monthYear=LOM18&strategy=DEFAULT&tradeDate=03/08/2018&pageSize=50&_=1520581128693";

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient)
{
    wc.BaseAddress = @"http://www.cmegroup.com/";
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";

    _jsonStr = wc.DownloadString(_tableUrlStr);
}

if (_jsonStr.IsNullOrEmpty())
    return; 

JObject jo = JObject.Parse(_jsonStr);

//## Add some more detail to the Json file.
jo.Add("instrumentName", "my instrument name");
jo.Add("contract", "my contract name");

//## For easier debugging but larger file size.
_jsonStr = jo.ToString(Formatting.Indented);


//## Json to file:
string path = directoryString + fileString + ".json";

if (!Directory.Exists(directoryString))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryString);
}

if (File.Exists(path))
{        
    return;
}

using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.CreateNew,  FileAccess.Write))
{   
     using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        streamWriter.WriteLine(_jsonStr);
        streamWriter.Close();
    }   
}

//## Json file to collection:
//## Can copy and paste your Json at 'www.json2csharp.com'.

public class Settlement
{
    public string strike { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string open { get; set; }
    public string high { get; set; }
    public string low { get; set; }
    public string last { get; set; }
    public string change { get; set; }
    public string settle { get; set; }
    public string volume { get; set; }
    public string openInterest { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Settlement> settlements { get; set; }
    public string updateTime { get; set; }
    public string dsHeader { get; set; }
    public string reportType { get; set; }
    public string tradeDate { get; set; }
    public bool empty { get; set; }
//## New added entries
    public string instrumentName { get; set; }
    public string contract { get; set; }
}

private static IEnumerable<Settlement> JsonFileToList(string directoryString, string fileString)
{
    if (directoryString == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    string path = directoryString + fileString + ".json";

    if (!Directory.Exists(directoryString))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryString);
    }

    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        return null;
    }

    RootObject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(File.ReadAllText(path));

    var settlementList = ro.settlements;

    foreach (var settlement in settlementList)
    {
    //## Do something with this data.
        Console.Writeline(String.Format("Strike: {0}, Volume: {1}, Last: {2}", settlement.strike, settlement.volume, settlement.last));
    }

    return settlementList;

}
```